# Stop activity when recent button or back button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-finish

In my app when I pressed the back button or the recents button (shows apps) and I go back into the app the value that is the users score begins doubling the original value.

I believe it has something to do with onResume running in the background and when they re-enter the app it runs twice. I have tried:

```
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop()
    finish();
}
```

But that ends the activity and when the user enters the second app the user goes to the second activity instead of the main one.

Here is the code for that activity:

```
package com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button myButton;
    private int Counter;
    private Button myButton2;
    private TextView myTextView;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int add;
    private TextView myAddView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            if (bundle.containsKey("Count")) {
                Counter = bundle.getInt("Count");
            }
            if (bundle.containsKey("Add")) {
                add = bundle.getInt("Add");
            }
        }

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myAddView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Counter = ButtonCounter(Counter);
            }
        });
        myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),                 SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Count", Counter);
                intent.putExtra("Add", add);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Counter = AutoCounter(Counter, add);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Display(Counter, add);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
            }
        }, 50);
    }



    public int ButtonCounter(int Counter) {
        Counter += 1;
        return Counter;
    }

    public int AutoCounter(int Counter, int add) {
        Counter = Counter + add;
        return Counter;
    }

    public void Display(int Counter, int add) {
        String money = String.valueOf(Counter);
        myTextView.setText("$" + money);
        myAddView.setText("Generating $" + add + "/Per Second");

    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain what you're are trying to achieve.

Comment: About back button you can `override` method `onBackPressed()` on your `activity`. But I am confused and don't know why you need to finish when clicking `recent app button` but not when another app overlaps your `activity`?